# how to rewrite specific URL to another subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, redirect

I have a joomla site at a server and the URLs work like **www.mysite.com/home**, **www.mysite.com/info**...etc.

However, I have another WordPress site (at another server **blog.mysite.com**) that containing the blog.

Is it possible of showing the contents of the blog while the user goes to **www.mysite.com/blog** but not changing the domain to **blog.mysite.com**?

That's mean every URL of the blog will become

www.mysite.com/blog

www.mysite.com/blog/article-1

www.mysite.com/blog/article-2

Comment: what you think about permalinks

Comment: Why not installing the WP instance in the subdirectory /blog and let the subdomain access this subdirectory as well?